# How to broadcast (push) a message send by one client, to all clients through a server using WCF NetHttpBinding (WebSockets)?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, websocket

In .NET 4.5 a new WCF binding- NetHttpBinding- has been introduced which uses WebSocket protocol as it's underlying transport. Which implies that this enables a true push from server. Now, I have been able to make some sort of push using A callback contract like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WebSocketSampleService : IDuplexContract
{
    public string SayHelloDuplex()
    {
        //push to the current caller
        OperationContext.Current.
            GetCallbackChannel<IDuplexCallbackContract>().
            SayingHello("Hello from WebSockets");

        //answer the current caller in the regular http way
        return "Hello";
    }
}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IDuplexCallbackContract))]
public interface IDuplexContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHelloDuplex(string name);
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDuplexCallbackContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SayingHello(string message);
}
```

What I would like to do though, is to broadcast the message to all clients when a single client calls the method `SayHelloDuplex()`. Is there a way to access the callback channels of all clients? Or should I record the callback channels of all the clients for later use in some other method (E.g. `Connect()`)? Perhaps I'm tackling this problem in the wrong way?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but this sounds like a scenario where SignalR may make your life easier.  Mileage will vary...

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT Thanks. I am doing my main semester project at Academy. I analyze ways to implement real-time communication in .NET. I have already written about SignalR and how it made my life easier. This is an alternative which I would like to analyze too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callback channel is unique per client, so there is no way to access the callback channel of all clients.

Instead you should save the callback channel for each client in a list or even better in a dictionary so you can target specific client.

Then when you want to broadcast a message to all clients just go over the list.